# How to direct replay to notifications of other apps from my android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, remote-input

I want to reply to the chat app's notification conversation from my app.

I did a code and get notification id,Remote Input key.But I can't figure out how to do it.

There are some apps on play store [app 1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.hexcoders.whatsdelete&hl=en&gl=US) and [app 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.malam.whatsdelete.unseen.viewdeletedmessages&hl=en&gl=US) which are doing this.

I read this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57726923/21697453) but it's unanswered and I can't comment on that question because of new account limitation so I asking new question.

So I need help to send reply to other apps notification from EditText of my app's screen